# Property relationships with Visual Studio 2010 Modeling Projects

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, uml

I have a problem. I need to create a UML design, but specifying for relationships between classes which properties are the ones relating the classes. I want to create a Visual Studio modeling project, but I can't seem to find how to associate specific properties of two classes in a class diagram. Is it possible?

Best regards,
David

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to do this is with associations. You don't add the attributes to the classes - instead, you draw an association between them. In UML, an association represents a pair of attributes. To give the attributes names, you set the role names on each end of the association. If you want to represent a pair of attributes, set IsNavigable=true on both roles.

Cheers
Alan

Comment: Thanks a lot Allan. I had already found a similar solution, now I see it was the correct one. I'm using the UML modeling diagrams to generate source code. BTW, is there a way to know in code the multiplicty of a relationship?